# How to add sub string to each element in a string seperated by comma

Tags: php

I have a string `'2437585','2437605','2437940','2438199'` 
I want to add '000' to each element in the  string like

```
'0002437585','0002437605','0002437940','0002438199'
```

Can any one help me out.

Comment: post code you tried

Comment: What you have tried so far !!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php appending strings is easy with operator ( . ) . For example $var = '000' and $var2 = '2437585' you can try echo $var . $var2; or $var .= $var2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the quickest fix would be preg_replace?
This should work:

```
$str = preg_replace("/'([0-9]{1})/","'000\\1",$str);
```

It is replacing every instance of a single quote followed by 1 number with a single-quote, then 3 zeros and then the number we matched

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace.

This finds a number with `"/(\d+)/"` pattern and adds the three zeros with `"000$0"` where `$0` means the match.

```
$str ="'2437585','2437605','2437940','2438199'";

Echo preg_replace("/(\d+)/", "000$0", $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/kpst6